# Is the difference between "page views" and "visits" in the site analytics tool documented anywhere?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, traffic, site-analytics

The [Site Analytics tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics), accessible to users with 25k reputation or more, includes a "Traffic" graph that has three curves:

- page views
- visits
- new visits

I was not sure what the difference between a "page view" and a "visit" was, so I searched for it on Meta. However, neither the [privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) nor the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931/643262) nor the [feature announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260849/643262) seem to contain this information. The announcement post contains the not so helpful sentence

> - **Traffic** — Includes the existing "Number of Visits", "Number of New Visits", and "Total Page Views" in one graph. The data series are relabeled "visits", "new visits" and "page views".

I finally found what I think to be the answer by reading about the common meaning of these two concepts on external websites (it seems that a "view" is counted every time someone loads an SE page, and a "visit" is counted only when someone loads a page coming from an external site).

Is this documented anywhere inside the SE network? If not, can it be documented? Something like a hover text on the words "page views" / "visits" would be helpful.

(I could add the explanation myself to the [feature announcement post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/260849/643262), but for that I would need to be sure that my interpretation of the meaning is correct).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These figures are copied directly from the Google Analytics API.

- [Page view](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6086080?hl=en) matches what you describe.
- A 'visit' is now called [Session](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6086069?hl=en); consecutive page views by the same user within 30 minutes count as a single session. (Also, if it's midnight, that will start a new session.) You do not necessarily need to come from an external site to count as a visit. More explanation and a helpful diagram can be found [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2731565).
- A 'new visit' ([new session](https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/6193585?hl=en)) is a visit by a user who hasn't been to the site before (at least not in the last 30 days, it seems).