# Is traffic from search engines included in the question view counts?

Tags: discussion, views, site-analytics

This should apply to all sites, but I'll write from the perspective of Arts & Crafts.  According to the analytics, 93% of our site's traffic is from search engines.  People don't use Google to look up the URL of our site main page (and then never look at a single post when they get there); virtually all of that traffic is to, or includes, a specific post.  That traffic is concentrated in questions that number in the hundreds.

The analytics report traffic by different measures, like visits and page views.  They're different but have a consistent relationship.
Our site supposedly gets in the ballpark of half a million visits per year from search engines.  Reported page views is substantially higher than visits.  The particular measure is irrelevant; my question concerns the reported general level of traffic, whatever measure you pick.

The question is not related to several suggested previous questions that relate to the difference between visit and page view counts, or inaccurate allocations of traffic or missing traffic in the analytics.  And those don't address the fundamental question in the title and in bold at the end of the question.

Traffic at that level should translate to many hundreds of questions having their view counts go up by a thousand views per year, some by double-digit thousands every year.  But if you look through our archive of questions, the patterns of view counts look like those visitors barely left a trace.

This suggests that either few, if any, of those visits are counted in the question views, or the total traffic reported in the analytics bears no relation to actual (which has credence because it is hard to believe that the actual traffic is anywhere near that, intuitively by more than an order of magnitude).

**Is traffic from search engines included in the question view counts?**

Comment: “repeat visits within 30 days don't increment the visit count” - how so? The view counter is IP-based and doesn’t increment only if a visitor from this IP has seen the post less than 15 mins ago, so it’s entirely possible that a single visitor makes multiple views (at least it is how it worked about 6-8 years ago, please correct me if something changed)

Comment: That data is notoriously bad quality, cf. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/121423/295232 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92915/295232. I wouldn't draw any conclusions from it.

Comment: @nicael, I based that on this answer: [Is the difference between "page views" and "visits" in the site analytics tool documented anywhere?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/356793/269940). But either way, the supposed quantity of visits doesn't appear to be reflected in the cumulative view counts on the questions.

Comment: What do you mean by "traffic from search engines"? From search engines search hits and/or from the search engines' [spiders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_crawler)? Presumably the former, but perhaps make it clear in the question?

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum, thanks. The question describes the search engine sources as whatever is reported in the analytics.  My understanding is that spiders are excluded from that.  If that is incorrect, maybe that's part of the answer.

Comment: A "view" and a "visit" are two **very** different numbers. Source: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36728/how-are-the-number-of-views-in-a-question-calculated#comment399465_36729 (and rest of page, and related). A visit is just that, but a view is filtered by IP address per hour; people can re-visit several times per hour but only view once.

Comment: @Rob, I had seen that page. Both views and visits have filters to avoid gaming and overcounting. People also arrive due to a search and then look at other posts, etc. So visits and views measure different things. But they're strongly related (patterns on the analytics are the same shape), and the numbers are dominated by search arrivals, which account for the vast majority of traffic. Views are always substantially higher than visits, so visits are a more conservative count, and that traffic isn't reflected on the questions. Could have worded that the views stats don't seems to match.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the difference between "page views" and "visits" in the site analytics tool documented anywhere?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356791/282094), and from a [CM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/309270/282094) and the [Dev](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/311989/282094) responsible.

Comment: @Rob, I had seen that thread.  I think people are getting sidetracked by what may have been my poor choice of traffic indicator, and visits vs. views. Most of those earlier threads about the analytics focused on not catching all the traffic, or not accurately allocating the traffic. My issue is that the level of traffic (pick your measure), being reported in the analytics seems insanely unrealistic; more than an order of magnitude higher than something that would make sense for the site, and the view counts on the questions don't seem anywhere near consistent with traffic at those levels.

Comment: fixer1234, thank you for editing your question. I think it's [implicit in the duplicate](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/356791/282094) that were there such documentation, or an answer there provided it, that it would answer this question: "Is traffic from search engines included in the question view counts?"; assuming a great answer is forthcoming. --- A duplicate (here on MSE) isn't required to have an answer, just that one for this question*could* be presented there; it appears that there's some agreement with that proposal. --- Another edit, and search for non-dupes, might rescue this Q.