# Why does SE track post referrers?

Tags: support, gdpr, referrals, export, json

I exported my SE data, and in `/qa/[site]\PostReferralsInbound.json` there are entries like

```json
{"postId":1732454,"ipAddress":"...","creationDate":"2021-05-09T21:12:27.533Z","referrer":"https://www.cargocultcode.com/solving-the-zalgo-regex/"}
```

How is this data used? I can't seem to find any place that the referral URIs for posts are displayed back to me.

Comment: The [Announcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer), [Booster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/booster), and [Publicist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/publicist) badges use an aggregate of this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's displayed in an aggregated fashion in the [site analytics page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/260849/proposed-micro-privilege-site-analytics). That's a [25K privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) on most sites.

I guess it's useful to see if any external sites are putting significant load on the Stack Exchange servers and whether that changes over time. If a search engine dropped off the map for instance then Stack Exchange could investigate why that happened perhaps. However the original post for site analytics did say that

> ...mostly the idea is to give a fun little perk to people who have given so much more to the community and the success of the site.