# "1 new answer to this question" usually fails to load any new answers

Tags: bug, live-refresh

When I see "1 new answer" I always click it. Much of the time it fails; this is often, but I don't think always, before/after posting an answer of my own.

I've seen this happen at least [once](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63276/neither-they-nor-i-am-idiot-at-all-or-neither-they-nor-i-are-idiots-at-all/) since gaining 2k on a beta site. In each of these cases, after reloading, no deleted answer is seen and a new answer is visible with the expected timestamp.

Later seen [on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300624/review-completed-but-the-question-still-shows-close-votes-edit-action-isnt-sho/300805?noredirect=1#comment229108_300805) after following a comment notification on an answer already left; the page had been loaded about 51 minutes before the new-answer notification appeared, per a userscript's tracking.

*Not* seen (that is, the new answer loaded as expected) [on RPG](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/66916/if-a-pc-loses-an-arm-are-there-any-mechanical-penalty-or-disadvantages) while drafting a new answer (which was not, as it happens, ever posted).

Seen again on SO while editing an already-posted answer.

Seen [on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/64046/difference-between-car-brand-and-car-make?noredirect=1#comment123697_64046) after finishing an edit to a question (without posting any answer at all).

Seen [on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/64083/meaning-of-this-quote-from-the-book-the-great-gatsby) after loading a page and leaving it for half an hour.

Seen [on M.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302436/plagiarism-from-wikipedia-survived-for-3-years-in-the-c-tag-excerpt?cb=1) after loading a page and leaving it for four minutes.

Seen [on ELL](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/65835/what-is-a-word-meaning-with-a-low-possibility?answertab=votes#65835) after loading a page and leaving it for 53 minutes. On the same page at the same time, live refresh of an edited post *did* work as expected.

Seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258390/why-is-duckduckgo-com-listed-as-referrer-rather-than-search-engine-on-analytics/261275?noredirect=1#comment862960_261275) after following a comment and leaving other comments.

Why is this?

I'm using `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:25.6) Gecko/20150723 Firefox/31.9 PaleMoon/25.6.0` — a Firefox fork on Win 8.1 x86. No other live-refresh functionality fails*, including new questions on the homepage using a very similar mechanism.

<sub>**Barring [any idea that there are new comments in certain review queues](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283827/check-for-new-comments-in-triage-review-queue-automatically), anyway.*</sub>

Comment: @durron597: Most recent example is http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63276/neither-they-nor-i-am-idiot-at-all-or-neither-they-nor-i-are-idiots-at-all/.

Comment: I'll check our http logs later today to see if I can narrow down which cog broke

Comment: Could it be that the answer was deleted before you clicked the notification?

Comment: @Shokhet: Nope, it's still there. I was expecting an answer per a previous comment, saw the "1 new answer" show up, clicked it, got nothing, then got another comment notification telling me the answer was up. If *two* answers were posted, but I only saw one of their notifications, and one of them was deleted....

Comment: Okay, worth checking.

Comment: This always fails at work (actually necessitates a refresh) and never fails at home. How rubbish is your internetz connection? Any VPNs? Overused lines?

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: It's occasionally a bit janky, but whenever that happens, all of SE tends to pretty obviously get messed up (ridiculously long load times, failed review loads, can't load rep dropdown, etc). Nothing special on the connection, it's just a fixed wireless broadband.

Comment: I've seen this happen on the main Stack Overflow site but always assumed the user deleted their post.

Comment: @BSMP: As you can see, I've kept a fairly careful log, making it highly improbable that all these events are deletions, and on ELL in particular (where I can see deleted posts) I can tell for a fact that that is not the case.

Comment: Sorry, my comment was unclear. I didn't mean that I don't believe this was an actual error; I saw that you already covered that possibility. It was supposed to be more of a, "I didn't say anything before because I didn't realize it was a problem, but I've seen this too".

Comment: What if the answer is immediately deleted after posting, but you just can't yet see it?

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος: What do you mean, can't see it *yet*?

Comment: @NathanTuggy I mean, there are no visual indications for the fact the answer is deleted, and you have <10k rep. I think such notifications are 2 minutes late. I also believe that the "new answer" notification never goes, if not clicked on. So, it can be misleading, but the real answer is then deleted.

Comment: @ΈρικΚωνσταντόπουλος: When this was reported, I had 2k on ELL, which was still using beta privileges. So yes, there would certainly have been visual indications.

Comment: @NathanTuggy Try refreshing then. I know the system can be bugged sometimes. I don't know if ti has been fixed, because there is no [tag:status-completed] tag there yet.