# Site analytics does not show DuckDuckGo as a referring site anymore, Help Center text should be changed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, help-center, site-analytics

Got the site analytics privilege recently at SO, and the [privilege page in the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) says:

> There are a few oddities in the data:
>
> • DuckDuckGo shows up [as a referring site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258390/why-is-duckduckgo-com-listed-as-referrer-rather-than-search-engine-on-analytics) and not a search engine.

But upon arrival, it's properly categorized:

[image: screenshot of Help Center]

I think the documentation needs to be updated!

Comment: It seems like [this feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315473/mark-duck-duck-go-as-a-search-engine-in-google-analytics?noredirect=1&lq=1) was implemented.

Comment: Still mis-described in the docs.

Comment: @ScottSeidman: It's been fixed by animuson now. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been fixed, the Help Center has been updated and no longer mentions DuckDuckGo.