# yandex.ru - Should this be a search engine in Site Analytics?

Tags: support, site-analytics

Just got my access to Site Analytics and noticed the the biggest referrer is yandex.ru, [which is Russian a Search Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yandex).

So given that it is one, maybe it should be placed in the Search Engines column.

[image: yandex.ru under "Referring Sites", Google under "Search Engines"]

This is not a duplicate of [Why is duckduckgo.com listed as referrer rather than search engine on analytics page?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/258390/why-is-duckduckgo-com-listed-as-referrer-rather-than-search-engine-on-analytics) as the answer there says that sites don't show as search engines if Google doesn't have it on the list of default search engines (DuckDuckGo wasn't on the list at the time). However, per the [most up to date listing of default search engines from Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795821?hl=en), Yandex *is* on their list of default search engines. As Google Analytics client sites can customize which sites are on their list of search engines, this needs a response from Stack Exchange as to why they decided to de-list Yandex or if the issue is somehow on Google's end.

Comment: I like their Net Income...ha ha.

Comment: While the question I linked to mentions another search engine, the answers apply here too.

Comment: @Laurel Not really a duplicate. The answer there is that Google lists several default search engines, and neither DuckDuckGo nor Yandex were ones at the time that question was posted. However, [the most up-to-date listing of the search engines from Google](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2795821?hl=en) *does* have Yandex in the list, so this is either a misconfiguration on SE's end (since GA users can customize which sites show as search engines in their analytics) or on Google's end. Per [this staff comment](/posts/comments/1263192), DuckDuckGo began appearing when Google added it

Comment: I agree with Laurel, and our cross-site duplicate is here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/305496/3648282

Comment: Ah, so it's an upstream problem...